# How to setup irregular subscription stripe payments

Tags: stripe-payments

How do I setup subscriptions with with fixed dates which are not regular intervals.
I have a scenario where users make 3 payments in one the follow patterns, ie fixed points not regular intervals.

```
if a customer signs up in Jul they pay Jul, Jan, May 
if a customer signs up in Aug they pay Aug, Jan, May
if a customer signs up in Sep they pay Sep, Jan, May 
if a customer signs up in Oct they pay Oct, Jan, May 
if a customer signs up in Nov they pay Nov, Jan, May 
if a customer signs up in Dec they pay Dec, Jan, May
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at subscription schedules: https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules